# Turn off user social registration in django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-registration, django-users, django-allauth

I noticed looking through the django-allauth templates there's a signup_closed.html users can be redirected to when user registration is closed or disabled. Does anyone who's familiar with that module know if there's a pre-configured setting that can be set in settings.py to turn off new user registration via existing social apps? Or do I need to configure that myself? I've read the full docs for allauth and I don't see any mention of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you need to override `is_open_for_signup` on your adapter.

See [the code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/d775602f128ce6c1e82f7a7722633c81b2ec18e7/allauth/account/adapter.py#L127).

Answer (score 8):

There is no pre-configured setting but it's easy to make one (this is what I do).

```py
# settings.py

# Point to custom account adapter.
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myproject.myapp.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter'

# A custom variable we created to tell the CustomAccountAdapter whether to
# allow signups.
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_SIGNUPS = False
```

```py
# myapp/adapter.py

from django.conf import settings

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter


class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        """
        Whether to allow sign ups.
        """
        allow_signups = super(
            CustomAccountAdapter, self).is_open_for_signup(request)
        # Override with setting, otherwise default to super.
        return getattr(settings, 'ACCOUNT_ALLOW_SIGNUPS', allow_signups)
```

This is flexible, especially if you have multiple environments (e.g. staging) and want to allow user registration in staging before setting it live in production.

Comment: This code does the trick.  However, let me add a warning label:  Implementing this custom adapter can prevent initial logins on social accounts, which can require operating signup methods to create the user's social account.  Users with pre-existing accounts will not be affected, but if you add a user to Azure AD (for example) and let them sign in with their microsoft ID, they'll be redirected to the non-working signup views, since their account can't be created automatically.

Answer (score 5):

More information at http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects.

You need to subclass `allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter` to override `is_open_for_signup`, and then set `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` to your class in `settings.py`

Comment: In case this helps others. I followed instructions above but named my custom adapter file `account_adapter.py` which is seems to be reserved name so it was giving `ModuleNotFoundError`. I had to rename it to something else eg `my_account_adapter.py` and then this worked.