# Allow only approved users django-allauth

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, user-registration, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth to allow users to login to a django app. I want users to be able to signup, but ONLY approved users should be able to access sensitive content. That is, a user who has signed up through the sign in page should have a pending status before accessing pages marked with the 'login-required' decorator.

I currently have django-allauth running with google-oauth2 login, and users are successfully added to my `user` table. Would anyone know how to set up such a system?

I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923692/turn-off-user-social-registration-in-django-allauth) post mentioning disabling signup all together, although I do want users to be able to signup, just approved, whether this is through the admin system or through an link generated that I would be able to click.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can add you replace @login_required with @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_approved) for sensitive content?