# How could one disable new account creation with django-allauth, but still allow existing users to sign in?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

We've been running a site for a while which uses [`django-allauth`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for authentication using any of:

- Traditional email-based sign-up
- Google login
- Twitter login
- Facebook login

... but now we want to stop anyone creating a new account, while still allowing people who've previously created an account using any of those methods to be able to log in. Is there a setting that will let us do this? It's not clear to me that any of [these documented settings](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) would allow us to configure that.

The current settings relating to django-allauth are:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    ...
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
               'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}},
    'facebook': {'SCOPE': ['email',]},
}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [question rnevius linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923692/turn-off-user-social-registration-in-django-allauth) fixed this for me. To add a bit more detail, I created a file `mysite/account_adapter.py` containing:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class NoNewUsersAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        """
        Checks whether or not the site is open for signups.

        Next to simply returning True/False you can also intervene the
        regular flow by raising an ImmediateHttpResponse

        (Comment reproduced from the overridden method.)
        """
        return False
```

And then added this to `mysite/settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite.account_adapter.NoNewUsersAccountAdapter'
```

Comment: In case this helps others. I followed instructions above but named my custom adapter file `account_adapter.py` which is seems to be reserved name so it was giving `ModuleNotFoundError`. I had to rename it to something else eg `my_account_adapter.py` and then this worked.

Comment: @curtisp Did you try putting it your app folder, like `mysite/`?

Comment: Ok thx didn't read answer completely. I had it in same folder as `settings.py` but just tried moving it to the `app` folder with `views.py`, etc and it does work named `account_adapter.py`.