# django allauth empty username causes duplicate key in postgress DB

Tags: django, django-allauth

Django 1.8.16
django-allauth  0.27.0
Using postgres as database.

My application does not use usernames, only e-mail addresses as user id.
So I use following settings:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```

Now when a new user registers, he uses his e-mail address.
But when submitting the registration form, I get this error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://swd.localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.8.16
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
```

This says exactly what is wrong: The empty username already exists in the auth_user table, field "username", and it seems this is not allowed?
But problem is that the username field is ALWAYS empty using above settings.
So how can we get around this?

I did not adapt the user model.

Comment: In the DB, the field 'username' is marked as 'unique'. So does this means indeed that it cannot be Null for all users. I can remove that 'unique' constraint at DB level, but there should be a more clean way to do this?

Comment: Removing this at DB level seems not straightforward, and is not the right thing to do. So how can we get around this?  Thx for your help.

Answer (score 8):

By doing this...

`ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None`

... you are telling allauth that your user model has no `username` field. In your case, that is clearly wrong, as you get a constraint error on that column. So, simply set it to `"username"` instead of `None` so that allauth will populate the field correctly.

Comment: So in fact if I set it to "None", I should remove that field from the user model? Or at least remove the "unique" constraint on that field. Fact is that it is there by default, so not using username field is not that straightforward as just setting ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD  to None as explained in many places including this rather official reference: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html

Comment: I has the same issue (same initial settings like Davy - and I also use Django DRF auth) . Setting ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' solved it. It create a username from the field before the '@'. Exemple : test@test.com would create a username 'test'. If test@test2.com registers, it adds strings to test, so the username remain unique. Actually, I do not need this uniqueness on the username field (if I display this to the user, it could not understand why is username is altered. But, it works and I can register users now.

Comment: If you set it to 'username' I find it doesn't pick up email as username, which I believe is the intention

Answer (score 4):

Solved by writing an allauth account adapter, which fills the user.username field with the email address:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.username = data['email']  # username not in use
        user.email = data['email']
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data['password1'])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()

        user.save()
        return user
```

Didn't change the settings.

Inspired by:
[How could one disable new account creation with django-allauth, but still allow existing users to sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794052/how-could-one-disable-new-account-creation-with-django-allauth-but-still-allow)

Comment: Just curious if you even tried to simply change the settings at all as per the other answer? After all, @pennersr is the main author of django-allauth so his suggestion probably made sense...

Comment: As commented above: since the username is marked as unique in the DB, changing ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD to None did not solve it for me ("duplicate key"). Maybe other settings have an influence as well?

Comment: I see. That setting is only changed for custom user models (e.g. if you call username 'personname' instead), which you don't have. Hence the real problem is that you cannot use blank usernames for the default user model (otherwise you get duplicates when everyone's username is '' (blank)). Your solution works because it stops username from being blank. However, unless you somehow make sure email is unique, it will fail if someone uses the same email twice (because their usernames will be duplicate).

Comment: Yes, email is unique in my solution as it maps 1-1 on an account.

Comment: This is largely suboptimal, as you are saving the same data(email id) twice for a record, a wrong thing to do. Consider adding the django-allauth package manually into your application and making minor tweaks to its logic.

Comment: I think this is a good solution for scenario above. I would just modify the username assignment to be limited to max 30 characters (per definition of the username field):

`user.username = data['email'][:30]`

Answer (score 0):

Here the error is due to the username field in the default Django User model.
You need to delete the username field from the User model. One thing you can do is override the user model. You can create a new custom User model in your app and set it as the default User model in settings.py

In models.py of your app

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Creating an email login.
    username = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

After Creating the User model configure it as default in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'

# Specify the username field of your model as well for all auth.
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

This should do your job.