# Avoid username field creation in custom user model for django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using a custom user model with allauth and I need to have the username field omitted. I've already seen the docs and a whole bunch of stackoverflow answers about using `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None` but all of this still leads my database to have an username field.

Now since the db still has an `username` field with the unique constraint set on **and** allauth will not put a username in the field with the aforementioned setting set to `None`, this causes me to face `IntegrityError` after the very first user creation. I know I can solve this by just having the aforementioned setting be set to `'username'` but I'm curious, how do I just not make the username, because I'm never using it.

My model:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Custom user model for django-allauth
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    def delete(self):
        # Custom delete - make sure user storage is also purged
        # Purge the user storage
        purge_userstore(self.email)
        # Call the original delete method to take care of everything else
        super(CustomUser, self).delete()
```

It doesn't really do much except override the `delete` function. This override is irrelevant in this topic but I included it just for the sake of completeness. It also sets `first_name` and `last_name` to `None`, which works perfectly and removes those fields from the database as expected. I've tried setting `user` to `None` but that does nothing. I've also tried setting `username` to `None` but that will raise a `FieldNotFound` error with `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None`

My settings (the relevant bit):

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_account.CustomUser'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

My migration file:

```py
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
....
```

This migration generation confuses me to no end. Why is the `username` field still there? Why is it set to be the only unique constraint even though I've clearly set `ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True`?

**Note**: This migration file is generated from a clean slate, this is the first and only migration file generated from the code I have presented.

At first I thought, my settings were simply not being read. But I checked `django.conf.settings` and `allauth.account.app_settings` (in the shell) for these changes and they were all updated. What's going on here?

**Note**: Amongst the many stackoverflow questions I've searched, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160475/django-allauth-empty-username-causes-duplicate-key-in-postgress-db) question in particular seems to explain my issue perfectly. With one small problem, the answer by the creator of allauth himself suggested to use `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "username"` as the model in question was "clearly using the `username` field". But the answer does not explain what to do when you don't want to use the `username` field at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the only way to get rid of the `username` field is to override the `AbstractUser`'s username field and/or use a completely custom model from the ground up. Thought overriding `AbstractBaseUser` should work too, albeit `AbstractBaseUser` provides less functionality.

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Custom user model for django-allauth
    # Remove unnecessary fields
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    # Set the email field to unique
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    # Get rid of all references to the username field
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

This model will remove the `username` field and make the `email` field unique, as well as change all references to the `USERNAME_FIELD` to `'email'`. Do note that `REQUIRED_FIELDS` should be empty as the `USERNAME_FIELD` cannot be in there. When using allauth, this is not a problem, the email and password requirement are managed by allauth anyway.

The settings that I've mentioned in the question should remain the same, specifically-

```py
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

Comment: I've done quite a bit of searching around, and this is one of the best/simplest answers I've found. However, when running `python manage.py createsuperuser` it gets mad about not having a user name (`TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'`) ... does this mean you have to implement a custom UserManager class?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary to override the manager class. The reason is that if we inspect the implementation of the create_superuser method, we can see that it expects the following signature: `def create_superuser(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):`. This means that it requires the username argument. If we want to modify this behavior, we must override the manager class.