# Django allauth Configuration

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I have implemented Django allauth as a method of authenticating users. I am using Django allauth in an attempt to try and handle multi user authentication system. Now when I omit "username" field in my forms.py file, Django complains of the integrity error as below.

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/accounts/student
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/accounts/student
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username
Exception Location: /home/offensive/Desktop/Target/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 357, in execute
Raised during:  accounts.views.StudentSignUpView
Python Executable:  /home/offensive/Desktop/Target/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/offensive/Desktop/Target',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/offensive/Desktop/Target/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 13 Feb 2023 14:14:23 +0000
```

below is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Student, User, Writer

class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            "email",
            # "username",
        ) 
    
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.is_student = True 
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        return user

class WriterSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            "email",
            # "username",
            "phone",
            "address",
        )
```

By default, I think Django allauth should populate username field automatically using the email address which I already made "required". Below is the Allauth configurations on my settings.py file.

```
..................
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

......
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
# # ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = "/"
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard"
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 3
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete your line `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "email"`. It seems you don't have a custom user model, and this setting is intended to tell Django which fieldname in a custom user model should be treated as what it expects to see as `username`. It's not related to telling Django which fieldname to use for validation.
2. Try using signals. Create a `signals.py` file in the same folder you have your `forms.py` for accounts:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings

User = get_user_model()

@receiver(pre_save,sender=User)
def set_username(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.username = instance.email
```

If that doesn't work, and if you haven't already, you should probably look into creating a custom user model, which is the recommended approach anyway.
[This article](https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-custom-user-model-allauth-for-oauth-20c84888c318) is a good starting point, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62080251) goes into how to get rid of the username field completely.