# Django Allauth: Duplicate Key Value Violates Unique Constraint: Key (username)=() already exists

Tags: python, django, forms, django-allauth

I have been troubleshooting an issue with my custom allauth Django user model for some time. I only want to use email, first name, last name, and password as part of my user signup form, and I can get it to work once, but when a second user signs up, it says that the username already exists. I have seen others with a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160475/django-allauth-empty-username-causes-duplicate-key-in-postgress-db), but unfortunately their solutions do not work. If I remove the custom account form, then it does, but I need to include first name and last name in my signup form, so not sure how to work around that. Any help is appreciated!

***settings.py***

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
# I have also tried ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' and ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' per the solution linked above, but that did not work for my use case

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
}
```

***models.py***

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

***forms.py***

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out an answer after playing around with it a bit and using Ankit's response as a template.

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(SignupForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 256)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 128)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 128)

    def save(self, request):

        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(request)
        user.save()

        return user
```

***settings.py***

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override django-allauth [`SignUpForm`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform) and save required fields in **`save()`** method.

```
from django import forms

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(SignupForm):

    email = forms.IntegerField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, request):

        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(request)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

Comment: I added this form, updated the settings file so that ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'accounts.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'}, but unfortunately I still get the same error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_customuser_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.